# Hiding text after typing using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

The following snippet below will type sentences "This is the first sentence ...", "This is the second sentence ... ", "This is the third sentence ...", "This is the forth sentence ..." with typewriter effect using angular.

Now, my question is, is there a way to remove the "This is the forth sentence ..." after the typing effect? I just want it to show all the sentences "once" not "loop".

```js
angular.module("angular.typewriter", [])
.directive("typewriter", ["$timeout", "$compile", function($timeout, $compile){
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    template: "",
    scope: {
      typeSpeed: '@',
      loop: '=loop',
      loopDelay: '@',
      customStyle: '=customStyle',
      cursor: '=cursor',
      shell: '=shell',
      messages: '=',
      newline: '=newline'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      //console.log("Typewriter directive...");
      
      scope.typeSpeed = scope.typeSpeed || 100;
      scope.loopDelay = scope.loopDelay || 2000;
      scope.customStyle = scope.customStyle || false;
      scope.cursor = scope.cursor || true;
      scope.shell = scope.shell || false;
      scope.newline = scope.newline || false;
      
      if(scope.cursor){
        var contentCursor = angular.element('<span class="cursor"> |</span>');
        contentCursor.insertAfter(element);
        $compile(contentCursor)(scope);
      }
      
      if(scope.shell){
        var contentShell = angular.element('<span class="shell" style="font-family: \'Consolas\', \'Courier New\', \'Courier\'">$ </span>');
        contentShell.insertBefore(element);
        $compile(contentShell)(scope);
      }
      
      scope.typewrite = function(element, text, n, loop){
        if(n<text.length+1){
          if(text.substring(n-1,n)=='<'){
            $timeout(function(){
              scope.typewrite(element, text, n+2, scope.loop);
            }, scope.loopDelay);
          }
          else{
            element.html(text.substring(0,n));
            $timeout(function(){
              scope.typewrite(element, text, n+1, scope.loop);
            }, scope.typeSpeed);
          }
        }
        else if(scope.loop) {
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite(element, text, 0, scope.loop);
          }, scope.loopDelay);
        }
      }
      
      scope.typewrite_msgs = function(element, text_array, array_idx, n, loop){
        if(n<text_array[array_idx].length+1){
          
          element.html(text_array[array_idx].substring(0,n));
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite_msgs(element, text_array, array_idx, n+1, loop);
          }, scope.typeSpeed);
        }
        else if(array_idx+1 < text_array.length){
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite_msgs(element, text_array, array_idx+1, 0, loop);
          }, scope.loopDelay);
        }
        else if(scope.loop) {
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite_msgs(element, text_array, 0, 0, loop);
          }, scope.loopDelay);
        }
      }
      
      
      if(scope.messages){
        
        if(scope.newline) {
          var whole_msg = '';
          angular.forEach(scope.messages, function(value, key){
            whole_msg = whole_msg + value + "<br>";
          })
          scope.typewrite(element, whole_msg, 0, scope.loop);
        }
        else {
          scope.typewrite_msgs(element, scope.messages, 0, 0, scope.loop, scope.newline);
        }
      }
      else {
        var text = element.html();
        //var length = text.length;
        //console.log(text + ": " + length);
        scope.typewrite(element, text, 0, scope.loop);
      }
      
      if(!scope.customStyle){
        element.css("font-family", '"Consolas", "Courier New", "Courier"');
        element.css("background-color", "#000000");
        element.css("color", "#f0f0f0");
      }
    }
  } 
}]);

var demoApp = angular.module("demoapp", ["angular.typewriter"]);

demoApp.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  
  console.log("Controller...");
  
  $scope.sentences = ["This is the first sentence ...", "This is the second sentence ... ", "This is the third sentence ...", "This is the forth sentence ..." ];
}]);
```

```html
  <html ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
  <style>
    .shell-input {
      display: inline-block; width:500px; height:40px; background-color: #000000;margin:auto; border-radius:10px;padding:10px;
    }
    .title {
      padding-top:20px;display:inline-block;float:left;margin-bottom:5px;font-family: RobotoDraft, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;font-weight:300;color:blue;
    }
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #949494;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
margin-bottom:60px;
  z-index:2;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
}
  </style>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" style="text-align: center;"> 
    <header>
    <h1>Angular Typewriter</h1>
    </header>
    
    <div style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">

      <span class="title">Messages One-line Loop, speed:150</span>
      <span class="shell-input" style="text-align:left;">
        <span class="typewriter" typewriter type-speed="50" loop=false messages="sentences" loop-delay="1000" custom-style=false cursor=true shell=false newline=false>Welcome, type-write your message here!</span>
      </span>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Any response would greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using onkeyup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the loop option to false will prevent the typewriting from looping your messages. The easiest way of emptying the output, is adding an empty message in the messages list.

I updated the code and added the blank space message in the list.

```js
angular.module("angular.typewriter", [])
.directive("typewriter", ["$timeout", "$compile", function($timeout, $compile){
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    template: "",
    scope: {
      typeSpeed: '@',
      loop: '=loop',
      loopDelay: '@',
      customStyle: '=customStyle',
      cursor: '=cursor',
      shell: '=shell',
      messages: '=',
      newline: '=newline'
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
      //console.log("Typewriter directive...");
      
      scope.typeSpeed = scope.typeSpeed || 100;
      scope.loopDelay = scope.loopDelay || 2000;
      scope.customStyle = scope.customStyle || false;
      scope.cursor = scope.cursor || true;
      scope.shell = scope.shell || false;
      scope.newline = scope.newline || false;
      
      if(scope.cursor){
        var contentCursor = angular.element('<span class="cursor"> |</span>');
        contentCursor.insertAfter(element);
        $compile(contentCursor)(scope);
      }
      
      if(scope.shell){
        var contentShell = angular.element('<span class="shell" style="font-family: \'Consolas\', \'Courier New\', \'Courier\'">$ </span>');
        contentShell.insertBefore(element);
        $compile(contentShell)(scope);
      }
      
      scope.typewrite = function(element, text, n, loop){
        if(n<text.length+1){
          if(text.substring(n-1,n)=='<'){
            $timeout(function(){
              scope.typewrite(element, text, n+2, scope.loop);
            }, scope.loopDelay);
          }
          else{
            element.html(text.substring(0,n));
            $timeout(function(){
              scope.typewrite(element, text, n+1, scope.loop);
            }, scope.typeSpeed);
          }
        }
        else if(scope.loop) {
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite(element, text, 0, scope.loop);
          }, scope.loopDelay);
        }
      }
      
      scope.typewrite_msgs = function(element, text_array, array_idx, n, loop){
        if(n<text_array[array_idx].length+1){
          
          element.html(text_array[array_idx].substring(0,n));
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite_msgs(element, text_array, array_idx, n+1, loop);
          }, scope.typeSpeed);
        }
        else if(array_idx+1 < text_array.length){
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite_msgs(element, text_array, array_idx+1, 0, loop);
          }, scope.loopDelay);
        }
        else if(scope.loop) {
          $timeout(function(){
            scope.typewrite_msgs(element, text_array, 0, 0, loop);
          }, scope.loopDelay);
        } else {
          scope.typewrite_msgs(element, [''], 0, 0, loop);
        }
      }
      
      
      if(scope.messages){
        
        if(scope.newline) {
          var whole_msg = '';
          angular.forEach(scope.messages, function(value, key){
            whole_msg = whole_msg + value + "<br>";
          })
          scope.typewrite(element, whole_msg, 0, scope.loop);
        }
        else {
          scope.typewrite_msgs(element, scope.messages, 0, 0, scope.loop, scope.newline);
        }
      }
      else {
        var text = element.html();
        //var length = text.length;
        //console.log(text + ": " + length);
        scope.typewrite(element, text, 0, scope.loop);
      }
      
      if(!scope.customStyle){
        element.css("font-family", '"Consolas", "Courier New", "Courier"');
        element.css("background-color", "#000000");
        element.css("color", "#f0f0f0");
      }
    }
  } 
}]);

var demoApp = angular.module("demoapp", ["angular.typewriter"]);

demoApp.controller("mainCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){
  
  console.log("Controller...");
  
  $scope.sentences = ["This is the first sentence ...", "This is the second sentence ... ", "This is the third sentence ...", "This is the forth sentence ...", " "];
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="demoapp">
<head>
  <style>
    .shell-input {
      display: inline-block; width:500px; height:40px; background-color: #000000;margin:auto; border-radius:10px;padding:10px;
    }
    .title {
      padding-top:20px;display:inline-block;float:left;margin-bottom:5px;font-family: RobotoDraft, Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;font-weight:300;color:blue;
    }
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  color: #949494;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
margin-bottom:60px;
  z-index:2;
  background-color: #3f51b5;
  padding: 1em 3em 1em 3em;
  color: #FFF;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  position: relative;
}
  </style>
</head>
  <body ng-controller="mainCtrl" style="text-align: center;"> 
    <header>
    <h1>Angular Typewriter</h1>
    </header>
    
    <div style="width:500px;display:inline-block;">

      <span class="title">Messages One-line Loop, speed:150</span>
      <span class="shell-input" style="text-align:left;">
        <span class="typewriter" typewriter type-speed="50" loop=false messages="sentences" loop-delay="1000" custom-style=false cursor=true shell=false newline=false>Welcome, type-write your message here!</span>
      </span>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js'></script>

  

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
```